# How do i install Command-T, Pathogen, and not using RVM?

Tags: ruby, vim, macvim, pathogen

I used `brew install` to install ruby (as opposed to RVM). I have on my system installed ruby 1.9.3p0. (OSX Lion)

I'm trying to install Command-T via pathogen. I can normally run rake, make, ruby, whatever, but when i enter into the 'Command-T' directory and try to run `rake make` it says `Could not find rake-0.8.7 in any of the sources`.

I also cant run any normal ruby command. just `ruby --version` produces the same errors.

I know this has to do with below... but i dont know how to actually fix it.

> Most installation problems are caused by a mismatch between the
>   version of Ruby on the host operating system, and the version of Ruby
>   that Vim itself linked against at compile time. For example, if one is
>   32-bit and the other is 64-bit, or one is from the Ruby 1.9 series and
>   the other is from the 1.8 series, then the plug-in is not likely to
>   work.
>
> As such, on Mac OS X, I recommend using the standard Ruby that comes
>   with the system (currently 1.8.7) along with the latest version of
>   MacVim (currently version 7.3). If you wish to use custom builds of
>   Ruby or of MacVim (not recommmended) then you will have to take extra
>   care to ensure that the exact same Ruby environment is in effect when
>   building Ruby, Vim and the Command-T extension.

I tried temporarily moving the entire Cellar directory out of /usr/local (for those arent familiar, its where homebrew installs ruby and everything else).

In terminal if i run which ruby it works right.. yet when i rune rake make in the Command-T folder it still gives the same error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nevermind... all i had to do was run `/usr/bin/rake make`

how thats different than just removing the Cellar folder temporarily so that by default shell uses that path, i have no idea, but it worked.

Comment: Made my day. I'll be happy for a logical explanation for this, though. Perhaps because your using `system` ruby?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem on Fedora.

In the end, I found we should install rubygem-rake and ruby-dev package first. 
After installing both,  compile your Vim with "./configure --enable-rubyinterp",
then Commend-T will be ok.